# code editor which is a standalone web application which helps us edit code from the browser?

Tags: web-browser, portable, source-code, editor

Looking for some code editor which is a spins up a web-based IDE on launch from the command line. It should have modern features most source code editors have (like vscode). The best use case for this is to enable code editing on server-based operating systems (that have no gui desktop programs). It should preferably be a simple binary/executable program with minimal dependencies, portable, and, opensource.

Edit: (24th Nov '22). Try [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server) (Disclaimer: I am not promoting it).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Online IDEs listed in the respective [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_integrated_development_environment) and linked articles (which list the respective licenses).

Of these I only know Cloud9 IDE and it was good, but then they were acquired by Amazon. Haven't used it since then.

You could also try [Rstudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/#rstudio-server) community edition. It is designed for R code but it can also deal with Markdown (compile), Latex (compile), Python? (compile). For SQL and Javascript and many other languages it has syntax highlighting, or some form of deeper integration.

To support this, Rstudio Server comes with a lot of dependencies, of course; and the other IDEs as well, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a version of vscode that runs in the browser - https://vscode.dev/

Not sure how much tweaking may be involved, but maybe you can get it to run as you need it.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode